# How to structure firebase data and assign rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

What I would like is a data structure similar to this rule structure. I don't seem to be able to accomplish this since adding a new record generates a new random token for that record. Basically a user should be able to run a query at /stores and see all stores that have a uid equal to the currently authenticated user. So there would be multiple records under store that had the same uid. I might be going about this completely wrong so my question is how to create a structure where logged in users can see records that belong to them.

```
{
    "rules": {
        "users": {
            "$uid": {
                ".read": true,
                    ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
            } 
        },
        "stores": {
            "$uid": {
                ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
                ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
                "$storeId": {
                }
            }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide more content for us, please. Generally a relationship in firebase will require an additional key:value pair. So you may be best doing this:

## user1

record1: true

record2: true

record3: false

## user2

record1: false

record2: false

record3: true

I found this post to be very helpful: https://www.airpair.com/firebase/posts/structuring-your-firebase-data

Comment: If you look at the link you referenced in the many to many section. How can I only allow users that belong to the group access to the data in that group? So if I ran a search under /groups it would only return the groups and data that user is in.

Comment: You can store the relationship under "users" or under "stores" but I wouldn't advise you store it under both. The example in the link shows this - using the user object and listing the specific groups each with a true or false. Your question leads me to think you may be trying to do too much at once and Firebase is setup for speed perhaps more than relationships. To your specific question: groups(or stores) would be all those set to "true" for that user. Getting a list of the detail of each store would require an additional call to firebase using either a name or id.